# Symfony Image Editing With Avairy Editor

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, amazon-s3, adobe

I am using Symfony2.8 With aviaryeditor Image Editor. The Scene is that I have from with one file upload field. I wanted to allow user to upload images and do some editing with images (cropping, resizing, effects) then upload it to the server. And on the backend i get the file. Do some checks and validation and upload it on my local file system of s3.

What i have done so far is, I allow user to upload the image from the user and dislay the uploaded image in the form. On image click the editors pops up and after editing the gives the new url (s3 url of avairy api).

```
$builder
    ->add('media', 'file', array(
        'data_class' => null,
        'label' => ucfirst('Choose Domicile File'),
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')
    )
)


<div class = "form-group col-xs-5">
    <label class="control-label">{{ form_label(domicileForm.media) }}</label>
    <div class="text-center">
        {{form_widget (domicileForm.media, {'attr': {'class':  'form-control'}})}}
    </div>
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image"
         class="img-responsive img-thunmbail"
         onclick="return launchEditor(this.id, this.src);" />
</div>
```

and with js

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function readURL(input) {
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }
            }

            $("#pncmisdashboard_bundle_dimicile_type_media").change(function(){
                readURL(this);
            });
        });
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://feather.aviary.com/js/feather.js"></script>
        <!-- Instantiate Feather -->
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
                apiKey: '43232',
                apiVersion: 3,
                theme: 'light', // Check out our new 'light' and 'dark' themes!
                tools:'crop,resize,color,sharpness,text',
                appendTo: '',
                onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
                    var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
                    $(imageID).attr('src', newURL);
//                    //copy the url to the hidden form field
//                    $('#pncmisdashboard_bundle_dimicile_type_media').val(newURL);
                    $('#pncmisdashboard_bundle_dimicile_type_media').attr('value', newURL);
                    img.src = newURL;
                    alert(imageID);
                    alert(newURL);
                    alert(imageID);


                },
                onError: function(errorObj) {
                    alert(errorObj.message);
                }
            });
            function launchEditor(id, src) {
                featherEditor.launch({
                    image: id,
                    url: src
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
```

and after the api successfully return the url of new image, I am setting this url to media (file type) field. But it's not happening. it saves the orignal image that was first upload not the new one.